# Empty HTML elements wraps the other with its content unintentionally

Tags: html, css, dom

I have problems with web product I'm working with. The problem happens in both `head` element, and `body`. So far I haven't find the exact pattern of the problem, so I think it's better to describe with examples.

Basically it turns :-

```
<head>
....
    <script src="abc.js"/>
    <script src="def.js"/>
....
</head>
```

into this in DOM :-

```
<head>
....
    <script src="abc.js">
        <script src="def.js"/>
    </script>
....
</head>
```

And also this :-

```
<body>
    <div><i class="fa fa-search"/></div>
    <div>abcdefg</div>
    ....
</body>
```

Into this:-

```
<body>
    <div><i class="fa fa-search"/></div>
    <div><i class="fa fa-search">abcdefg</i></div>
    ....
</body>
```

I have even tried disabling JS entirely (using Chrome developer tool, and FireFox NoScript extension), and the problems are still there.

The problem is there for quite a long time. We fill these empty elements with `<span />` so they are not empty anymore. However I feel guilty to do something like `<script src="jquery.js"><span /></script>`.

Can you please suggest what should I do to find the cause ? Also, please share if you've found something like this before. Thank you.

Edit: The problem happens on IE, FF, and Chrome.

Edit: I've noticed that the html was wrong. The HTML is corrected. This HTML is generated from XSL processor.

Comment: Can I check where the problem is: is the page output ok ... and it is just the DOM processing that's odd? Or is the page output itself incorrect? [That may lead to questions about what product you are using to generate the page; or code samples to see how you are loading the page into DOM.]

Comment: Page output is incorrect, as well as the DOM. Basically the icon from Font Awesome shows in every div I have.

I've found that the actual html has `script` tag written as `<script src="abc.js"/>`. (the `<i>` is output like this as well).  This might be the cause. I'll update the question.

Comment: Even I was facing this issue, properly closing the tag as suggested and putting space like `<i>&nbsp;</i>` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

After I've noticed that the actual output html is `<script src="abc.js"/>` not `<script src="abc.js> </script>`, I did some more research and found the `<script>` tag cannot be self-closing.

I've tried replacing self-closing tags with non-self-closing, and the results is good. So I think this the cause of the problem.

Lesson learnt today (for me): Avoid using self-closing when the output is HTML, not XML.

Edit: There is not such thing as self-enclosing tag in HTML.